# Can I speed up processing live video from webcam

Tags: python, performance, opencv, frame-rate, mediapipe

I'm trying to make a project where I need live smooth footage from my webcam in opencv. (I want to read hand gestures from webcam, and do something when certain gesture is detected) When I try to process webcam footage with mediapipe library, framerate drops to the point where reading gestures is super difficult because of missing frames. I'm kinda lost because I feel like I tried everything, and max I have is 22fps. I'm also lost because I don't know how much is this issue with my hardware, and how much with something I could code better.

My CPU: Ryzen 5 1600 AF

This is what I have so far,

```
from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream
import cv2 as cv
import mediapipe as mp
import time

mp_hands = mp.solutions.hands
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

vs = WebcamVideoStream(src=0).start()

# FPS handler, to show actual framerate inside a loop
def fps_handle(start):
    end = time.time()
    total_time = end - start
    if total_time != 0:
        fps = 1 / total_time
        print(f"FPS: {round(fps, 2)}")
        cv.putText(frame, f"FPS: {int(fps)}", (20,70), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255,0,255), 2, 1)
    else:
        print(f"FPS: ???")
        cv.putText(frame, f"FPS: ???", (20,70), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255,0,255), 2, 1)


with mp_hands.Hands(
    min_detection_confidence = 0.5,
    min_tracking_confidence = 0.3) as hands:

    # Main loop
    while(True):
        frame = vs.read()
        start = time.time()


        """All processing of the image take place here"""
        results = hands.process(frame)
        if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for hand_lm in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, hand_lm, mp_hands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        """End of processing image"""

        fps_handle(start)

        # cv.imshow('Video',frame)
        if cv.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
```

So my questions are:

Is there anything I can do to speed that up?

Is my CPU too slow, and I won't squeeze much more from it?

Am I trying something that's impossible or super hard for someone who just starts with opencv?

Or maybe it is wrong approach to this kind of a problem?

Comment: In general, hand tracking is a bit expensive and the computation is not always optimized either. Thus, it is often better to reduce the image size in the first place so to massively reduce the amount of computation while the precision is not so much affected. One indication of the performance of libraries is to just see if all cores are used. A parallel library is not guaranteed to be efficient but a serial one is nearly always inefficient. The ones that use the GPU tends to be also more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

A simple tweak you can use is to change the model difficulty to 0 (default is 1). This can help you increase FPS by ~30% at the cost of losing some accuracy.

```
...
with mp_hands.Hands(
    static_image_mode=False,
    model_complexity = 0,
    max_num_hands=2,
    min_tracking_confidence = 0.5,
    min_detection_confidence=0.5) as hands:
...
```

In my experience, resizing the input image does not improve performance, probably because of the image transformation that is performed as part of the processing pipeline. To confirm this statement, I ran a small benchmark, which does not claim to be complete at all :) .

```
Image        Model complexity   Time (500 runs)
1000 x 667   1                  12.79 s
100 x 67     1                  12.8 s
1000 x 667   0                  8.48 s
100 x 67     0                  8.22 s
```

The best option is to compile mediapipe with CUDA (if you have Nvidia card), but it can be tricky.
For my own proposes I have compiled MediaPipe 0.8.9 with CUDA for Jetson Nano (there is also Wheel package): https://github.com/anion0278/mediapipe-jetson

I think this could be a starting point for you if you decide to go for the compilation.